# How to determine IP for containers in host ubuntu machine docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-4.2

When I do `echo $DOCKER_HOST`, I get blank data.

I have 3 containers running started, with below compose file:

```
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  volumes:
    - air_scout-mongodb:/data/db
app:
  build: .
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV
  links:
    - db
  expose:
    - "3000"
web:
  build: .
  dockerfile: config/containers/Dockerfile-nginx
  links:
    - app
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

And below is the contents of /etc/hosts file for all 3 containers including host ubuntu:

```
host /etc/hosts content
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  127.0.1.1 bajratech-codemilan-pc
  192.168.99.100  air_scout.docker
  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
web container nginx /etc/hosts contents. // container id = 04f4b2a137db
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  172.17.0.3  airscout_app_1 50a8bbe3d0f9
  172.17.0.3  app 50a8bbe3d0f9 airscout_app_1
  172.17.0.3  app_1 50a8bbe3d0f9 airscout_app_1
  172.17.0.4  04f4b2a137db
app container unicorn /etc/hosts contents. // container id = 50a8bbe3d0f9
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  172.17.0.2  airscout_db_1 4743428b65c4
  172.17.0.2  db 4743428b65c4 airscout_db_1
  172.17.0.2  db_1 4743428b65c4 airscout_db_1
  172.17.0.3  50a8bbe3d0f9
db container mongodb /etc/hosts contents.  // container id = 4743428b65c4
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  172.17.0.2  4743428b65c4
```

I'm Unable to access web(nginx) container in my host machine, How can I find it?

Comment: `docker ps` ? it will display IP and port. On your host, if your start your containier, the ip will be the ip of your machine (so localhost will work). What you may looking for instead is the port, that `docker ps` will display

Comment: thanks for quick response @dwursteisen, but I have address as "0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp" when i do docker ps.

Comment: it means that your container expose the port 80 and the port 443. And that  the port 80 of your container can be accessed by the port 80 of your local machine. So you can try `telnet localhost 80` to be connected to your nginx

Comment: I did netstat -tulpn | grep :80 to view which process is using port 80 and the result is as "tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4300/docker-proxy". Is this info. pointing right. And when i did telnet localhost 80 the o/p is as "Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'." and after few minutes i get "Connection closed by foreign host." Any Idea.

Comment: it means it works as expected ! You're connected to your nginx. Try using a web browser on `http://localhost`, it will access to your nginx. And if it is well configured, will redirect your request to your rails web app.

Comment: thanks alot @dwursteisen, I will try to debug my problem and will report ASAP for the solution.

Comment: thanks alot @dwursteisen, I found the issue, the was with not setting of $RAILS_ENV and $SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variables properly, I set them in .yml config file and the app we working now smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `port` configurations and make sure they are properly binding. Another good place is to look at the logs after running `docker-compose up`.

Also make sure your `.env` file is containing all required environment variables, mainly `SECRET_KEY_BASE` for rails app.

Comment: thanks for the information provided @przbadu, the issue was really with not setting properly the $RAILS_ENV and $SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variables and I fixed them and the app is live now. Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 1):

To know on which IP/port is running your container, you can use the command `docker ps`

`docker ps`will display which container are running, and which port each container use and export. (see the port column)

```
 $ docker ps
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
4c01db0b339c        nginx                 bash                   17 seconds ago       Up 16 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp       nginx1
```

In this example, the port 80 of the container is mapped to the port 80 of your machine. It means that you can access to your container through the port 80 of your machine, using a telnet command for example :

```
 telnet localhost 80
```